# how grpc allow different version between client and server languages

Tags: grpc

I use grpc to connect python and node, in python the version is 1.39, in node the version is 1.37. will grpc allow this version difference ? and how it achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

As long as those follow the same gRPC protocol, they should work together. Therefore, your case should work.